# Can't seem to force image download even with output buffering on

Tags: php, image, http-headers

Ok, here's my code:

```
$file='dir/xxx/'.$images[0].'.jpg';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'.jpg"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

When I inspect my headers, they seem to be `Content-Type:text/html` and not my intended type.
It just outputs image raw data to the screen.
Please help!

Later edit:
**I've removed every ob_* control functions, the result is the same**.

Comment: I dont think you want to buffer the headers like that...

Comment: @prodigitalson Please come with a valid suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure headers arent already being sent elsewhere in the application?

Comment: headers are not sent anywhere else. if they were, shouldn`t I receive a warning message?

Comment: Possibly, but if display_errors is off or the error_reporting level excludes that warning then no, you wouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

ob_clean destroy the output buffer, clearing your header.

Also you don't need that `ob_*` function, you can safely remove that

Comment: @Gabriel: try in another browser or clean completly all cache of your browser

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a reason to buffer your headers in the first place, so you could probably remove them.

If you don't want to, here's the problem. You clean your buffer before you flush it. Try removing `ob_clean()`. Also, you may have to use `ob_flush()` instead of `flush()`.

Comment: Does it still see the Content-Type as being `text/html`? Have you tried testing in another browser?